# nodejs pass parameter after parameter

Tags: node.js

I know that the title looks crazy

but here is the problem

i have a function with 2 parameter both have default value

```
function a(author="unknown" message="my message"){
...
}
```

i can access it using a("john", "hello")

but what if i need to change only the 2nd parameter?

a("","hello")

if i set the first param to "" it change the default

so i need to do?

i want is a(default,message="new message")

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to achieve this is if you can modify the function to accept an object then you can choose which parameters to pass in.

```
function a({ author="unknown", message="my message" } = {}){
...
}
```

then to call it

```
a({ message: "new message" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your function in the below manner.
eg.

> a(undefined, "new message")

This will take default value of author and take message parameter.
This is answered properly in one of the question. Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68158567/nodejs-pass-parameter-after-parameter/68158750#68158750)

Comment: is this will not change the default value?

Comment: No this will not change the default value of 1st parameter and change value of only second parameter. Give it a try once.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, no, there is no way in js to get parameters by name, only by order.
You can always consult the docs for that information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Comment: sad i hope nodejs notice this maybe i need json